# Redirect url in mockserver

Tags: node.js, middleware, mockserver

I have a route in mock-server like this:
http://localhost:1337/mock-store/admin/store-parameters/1
which returns back a json:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "code": "123",
  "redirect": true
}
```

I want that if the json includes "redirect = true", the route will redirect me to a different link.

I'm trying to use middleware.js inside my yotpo-mock server, for example:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  req.header('X-Hello', 'Goodbye');
  res.header('X-Hello', 'World');
  next("www.google.com)
}
```

but the json response simply changed to "google.com".
I want my route to be redirected to google.com.

HELP?

Comment: can you use `res.redirect('google.com')`?

Comment: I tried, but it redirects to: http://localhost:1337/mock-store/admin/store-parameters/google.com, and I want it to redirect to google.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use `res.redirect`. But in order to redirect to a completely different website you must provide a fully qualified url (with the protocol and everything)

```
res.redirect('http://google.com');
```

Tried this POC and it works:

```
const app = require('express')();
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.redirect('https://google.com');
})
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('Hello');
})
app.listen(8089, ()=>{
    console.log('Running server');
})
```

Refer here: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!